# Struts2 display stream pdf

Tags: struts2

I want to display pdf stream in the new popup windows, but when the stream is empty, I want to write a error message in the current page (Edition.jsp)

In the Edition.jsp page :

```html
<s:form id="pdf" action="ExportPdf" theme="simple" target="pageEdition" >  
   ...
    <sj:menu name="typeEdition" cssClass="edition" list="listeEditions" />
</s:form>
```

In struts.xml :

```xml
<action name="ExportPdf" class="ExportPdfAction">
   <result name="success" type="stream">
       <param name="inputName">inputStreamPdf</param> 
       <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param> 
       <param name="contentDisposition">filename="myFile.pdf"</param> 
       <param name="bufferSize">2048</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error">/WEB-INF/web/Edition.jsp</result>          
</action>
```

javascript, when I click on the menu item edition

```js
$('.edition').bind('click', function(even, data) {
   window.open('', 'pageEdition', 'location=no, menubar=no, height=600, width=900' );
   $('#pdf').submit();        
   });
```

When I return error, I don't want to go in the target page.

---

Yes, I try it via Ajax JQuery, but now, the problem is for display pdf !

```js
//  click on the menu item edition
$('.edition').bind('click', function(event, data) {
    $('#pdf').submit();       
}); 

$('#pdf').submit(function(event) {
    // stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // post with parameters 
    var posting = $.post( $( this ).attr( 'action' ), $('#pdf').serialize());

    // wait results
    posting.done(function( data, event ) {
    if (data.substring(0,4) != '%PDF') {
       alert ("error");         
    } else {
       // the format pdf is recognize, but not display (the stream is in the url, but not in the content)
       window.open('data:application/pdf,'+ data, 'pageEdition', 'menubar=no, height=600, width=900' );
    }   
});
```

When I use this solution, the stream response (data parameter) is not display correctly. The stream is in the url but not in the content.
I try with :

```xml
window.document.write(data);
```

but it's html content.
How can I display pdf stream in javascript ?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to do anything that allows staying on the same page then you need to do it via Ajax. In this case you'd want to open a new window/tab on success w/ the link to `ExportPdf`, and on error, update your existing DOM.

Comment: I don't anderstand. How can I display the pdf stream ?